# Spark transformation from variable length CSV to pair RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to scala spark, I have a CSV file as given below.

```
R001, A, 10, C, 30, D, 50, X, 90
R002, E, 40, F, 70, G, 80, H, 90, J, 25 
R003, L, 30, M, 54, N, 67, O, 25, P, 85, Q, 100
```

How do I convert it to Pair RDD with first value of row as Key and having the numeric values skipped?

```
R001, A
R001, C
R001, D
R001, X
R002, E
R002, F
R002, G
R002, H
R002, J
R003, L
R003, M
R003, N
R003, O
R003, P
R003, Q
```

I tried this and it is looking ok, but I thought there is a lot better way to do this.

```
def isNumeric(str:String): Boolean = str.matches("[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")

def process(field: Array[String]): Array[String] = { 
 val results = new Array[String](field.length)  
 for (i <- 1 to field.length-1) {
    if(!isNumeric(field(i).trim) && field(0)!=null && field(i)!=null)
     results(i)= field(0)+":"+field(i)
 }  
  results  
};

 def skipNulls(input : String) : String = {  
  if(input!=null && input.trim!="" && input.contains(":")) {
  var res = input.split(":")    
  res(0)+","+res(1)
  }  else {
    "null"
  }
};


val a= raw_csv.map(_.split(",")).flatMap(k => process(k))
val b= a.map(k => skipNulls(k))
val c = b.filter( x => x.contains("null")==false)
val d= c.toDF()
d.show
display(d)
```

Comment: Updated the question and added what I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you largely have the right idea for the Spark parts (it doesn't look like you actually get to your desired RDD, though? I'm assuming you know this) and the question is whether we can clean up `process` and `skipNulls`. Because you're using `flatMap`, I think you should be able filter out the bad points in `process`.

If I'm understanding properly, you're introducing the nulls (and then removing them later) because you have this fixed-length array. However, we can separate the "key" and "values", filter to the non-numeric values, and then assemble the pairs we want without having to create this array. Something like:

```
def process(line: String): List[(String, String)] = {
  val key :: values = line.split(",").toList
  values.filterNot(isNumeric).map(key -> _) // equivalent to .map(x => (key, x))
}
```

This combines your first few steps, so my version would be `raw_csv.flatMap(process)` to get to the `RDD[(String, String)]`.

The splitting apart the list is arguably a little magic. The following would also work:

```
val elements = line.split(",")
val key = elements.head
val values = elements.tail
```

You could rewrite `isNumeric` as:

```
def isNumeric(s: String): Boolean = Try(s.toFloat).isSuccess
```

I don't have a strong opinion on whether that is better or worse than the regex. `Try` is in `scala.util`.

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

In case you're up for a different approach, you could simplify the solution by first transforming each line of your csv text into two strings: the key and the rest of the line (hence circumventing the variable-length problem).

STEPS: 1) divide each line of your source text file into an array of key string and remainder string by splitting at the first `","`, 2) remove all numeric fields in the remainder string using replaceAllIn() and split it into an array, and, 3) flatten the (key, array) elements into the wanted key-value pairs.

```
val numericField = """\s*[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*,?""".r

sc.textFile("/path/to/csvFile").
  map( _.split(",\\s*", 2) ).
  map{ case Array(key, remainder) =>
    (key, numericField.replaceAllIn(remainder, "").split(",\\s*")) }.
  flatMap{ case (k, arr) => arr.map( (k, _) ) }
// res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[21] ...

res1.collect
// res2: Array[(String, String)] = Array(
//   (R001,A), (R001,C), (R001,D), (R001,X),
//   (R002,E), (R002,F), (R002,G), (R002,H), (R002,J),
//   (R003,L), (R003,M), (R003,N), (R003,O), (R003,P), (R003,Q)
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

hoyland posted the answer.

I am just providing the complete code again

```
val raw_csv = sc.parallelize(Array(R001, A, 10, C, 30, D, 50, X, 90
R002, E, 40, F, 70, G, 80, H, 90, J, 25 
R003, L, 30, M, 54, N, 67, O, 25, P, 85, Q, 100))

import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
def isNumeric(s: String): Boolean = Try(s.toFloat).isSuccess

def process(line: String): List[(String, String)] = {
  val key :: values = line.split(",").toList
  values.filterNot(isNumeric).map(key -> _) 
}

val processed = raw_csv.flatMap(k => process(k))
display(processed.toDF)
```

result is as follows

```
R001, A
R001, C
R001, D
R001, X
R002, E
R002, F
R002, G
R002, H
R002, J
R003, L
R003, M
R003, N
R003, O
R003, P
R003, Q
```